# How to display less content of connection error in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been watching a video about basic connection to MySQL in PHP. And tried to hide the content of error from "Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: php_network_getaddresses...." to for example "Error 2002". I tried some of ways but it still shows the whole text. My code:
I also tried to use try/catch block but it still shows the whole text. I use vs code and PHP 8.1

```
   <?php 
     require_once "connect.php";

      $connection = @new mysqli($host,$db_user,$db_passw,$db_name);

      if($connection->connect_errno != 0){
       echo "Error ".$connection->connect_errno;             // <- this place
       //echo mysqli_report($connection->connect_errno);
       //die($connection->connect_errno);
       }else{
         $login = $_POST['username'];
         $passw = $_POST['password'];
  
        $connection -> close();
      }
   ?>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
............

```
      try {
         $connection = @new mysqli($host,$db_user,$db_passw,$db_name);
       } catch (Exception $e) {
               echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
      }

      ...........
```

Comment: "*I also tried to use try/catch block*" Can you show us how did you try to use try-catch?

Comment: Since it's not about phpMyAdmin, I removed that incorrect word from your question

Comment: The second example works for me. What exactly happens with try-catch and why do you say it's not what you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows the full error message because you literally ask for it:

```
echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
```

If you want to display the numeric error code, just do so:

```
echo 'Error ', $e->getCode(), "\n";
```

Something to note is that [mysqli_report()](https://php.net/mysqli_report) does not seemingly prevent *all* warnings. It feels like an implementation oversight, but I don't have more information about it. For that, the error suppression operator `@` you're already using should suffice.

Also, don't forget to disable the `display_errors` directive in your production server.

Finally, Mysqli only throw exceptions on errors by default since PHP/8.1. In earlier versions you need to set it explicitly:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```